# can not access environment variable specified by user provided service with java

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have created a user provided service as follows:

```
cf cups myservice -p '{"db": "text"}'
```

and I bind this service to my app, the service name is `myservice`. 
When i use cf env command, i can see the message:

```
"user-provided": [{
    "credentials":{
        "db":"text"
    },
    "name":"myservice"    
}]
```

but when i access this variable with java

```
System.getenv("cloud.services.myservice.db")
```

is null. Why can't I access the `db` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `cf env` on your app, you see an environment variable named `VCAP_SERVICES` that contains a JSON data structure like you showed:

```
VCAP_SERVICES: {
  "user-provided": [
    { 
      "credentials":{ "db":"text" }, 
      "name":"myservice"
    }
  ]
}
```

Your application can retrieve this JSON structure with `System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES")`. You can then parse the JSON returned from that call into a `Map`, for example, and retrieve the values needed.

There is no environment variable available to your app named `cloud.services.myservice.db`, so `System.getenv("cloud.services.myservice.db")` won't return anything useful.

Spring Boot parses the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable and creates Spring environment properties like `cloud.services.myservice.credentials.db` and `vcap.services.myservice.credentials.db`. These properties can't be retrieved with `System.getenv()` because they exist only in the Spring environment abstraction, not in the OS environment. This is described nicely in a [Spring blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/27/binding-to-data-services-with-spring-boot-in-cloud-foundry#a-purely-declarative-approach). More details are in the Spring Boot [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.html).

Answer (score 0):

Services In CloudFoundry are presented JSON blob in the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable.

In Java you will be able to get an object with all the services with:

```
JSONObject vcap = new JSONObject(System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"));
```

https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html for more information on provided environment variables.